# Вопрос по авторизации

Tags: веб-программирование, perl

Всем привет!
Есть у меня старенький Perl-скрипт под паролем. На форме поля login/password, всё как обычно. Пароль проверяю так:

```
$crypt_pass = crypt($in{'password'},$in{'login'});

open(PASS,"<$f_pass");
@crypted_pass = <PASS>;
chomp(@crypted_pass);
close(PASS);

foreach $line_pass(@crypted_pass) {
if($line_pass eq $crypt_pass) { Авотризация пройдена last; }
}

$in{'login'} - одинаковый, в <select>
```

В файле несколько паролей, не суть. В данный момент пароль в файле один.
Так вот. Пароль например цифровой - 192874645
Пускает даже если убрать до трех цифр с конца! Это что, хэш-коллизии эти или я что то не понимаю? Там у меня не банковские тайны, фиг с ним, но просто интересно почему crypt() так отрабатывает. Давно эту фишку приметил, да не с руки было. А сейчас делаю авторизацию и вот вспомнил про это.

Comment: Если делаете новую авторизацию, то делайте не с crypt, а с более современными и безопасными методами вроде pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt или argon2 (правда, реализаций для perl посоветовать не могу)

Comment: Traditionally the result is a string of 13 bytes: two first bytes of the salt, followed by 11 bytes from the set [./0-9A-Za-z], **and only the first eight bytes of PLAINTEXT mattered**. But alternative hashing schemes (like MD5), higher level security schemes (like C2), and implementations on non-Unix platforms may produce different strings.